# How to get ARM's condition code for GE as (N = V)?

Tags: arm, logic

[image]

From ARM assembly book, I have this table to check condition from N (negative) and V (overflow) flags. With the adder circuit as follows, I'm trying to understand what makes GE (Greater than or Equal) condition can be checked with (N = V). I can check this condition works fine with some tests.

[image]

Case1: When the result is positive or zero, there should be no overflow.

1. When x == y, N = 0, V = 0 => N = V OK
2. When x > y (1 > 0), N = 0, V = 0 => OK
3. When 0 > -1, N = 0, V = 0 => OK

Case2: When there is an overflow, the result should be negative.

1. In 2 bit system, b01 (1) - b11 (-1) = b10 (-2), V = 1 & N = 1 (the result is negative)

My question is how one can derive this condition, preferably mathematically?

Comment: V is signed overflow not unsigned overflow which is the carry flag.  How you do it is write a trivial program to work through some cases, three bit numbers work as well as 32 as well as 417 bit so you only need to see a small number of cases to see this work.  it is also very important that you distinguish GE as signed greater than equal (N == V) vs unsigned greater than or equal  CS/HS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that this has been asked and answered already on SO.  not sure when/where.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;
    unsigned int xa,xb,xc;
    unsigned int za,zb,zc;
    unsigned int rd;
    int sa,sb,sc;
    unsigned int n,v;

    for(ra=0;ra<=7;ra++)
    {
        for(rb=0;rb<=7;rb++)
        {
            rc=ra-rb;

            xa=ra&3;
            xb=(~rb)&3;
            xc=xa+xb+1;


            za=ra&7;
            zb=(~rb)&7;
            zc=za+zb+1;

            if(((xc>>2)&1)!=((zc>>3)&1))
            {
                v=1;
            }
            else
            {
                v=0;
            }

            n=(rc>>2)&1;
            sa=ra; if(sa&4) sa|=0xFFFFFFF8;
            sb=rb; if(sb&4) sb|=0xFFFFFFF8;
            sc=rc&7; if(sc&4) sc|=0xFFFFFFF8;

            for(rd=4;rd;rd>>=1) if(rd&ra) printf("1"); else printf("0");
            printf(" - ");
            for(rd=4;rd;rd>>=1) if(rd&rb) printf("1"); else printf("0");
            printf(" = ");
            for(rd=8;rd;rd>>=1) if(rd&rc) printf("1"); else printf("0");
            printf(" %u %u ",n,v);
            printf("(%+2d) - (%+2d) = (%+2d) ",sa,sb,sc);
            if(n==v) printf("*"); else printf(" ");
            if(sa>=sb) printf("x"); else printf(" ");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

000 - 000 = 0000 0 0 (+0) - (+0) = (+0) *x
000 - 001 = 1111 1 0 (+0) - (+1) = (-1)   
000 - 010 = 1110 1 0 (+0) - (+2) = (-2)   
000 - 011 = 1101 1 0 (+0) - (+3) = (-3)   
000 - 100 = 1100 1 1 (+0) - (-4) = (-4) *x
000 - 101 = 1011 0 0 (+0) - (-3) = (+3) *x
000 - 110 = 1010 0 0 (+0) - (-2) = (+2) *x
000 - 111 = 1001 0 0 (+0) - (-1) = (+1) *x
001 - 000 = 0001 0 0 (+1) - (+0) = (+1) *x
001 - 001 = 0000 0 0 (+1) - (+1) = (+0) *x
001 - 010 = 1111 1 0 (+1) - (+2) = (-1)   
001 - 011 = 1110 1 0 (+1) - (+3) = (-2)   
001 - 100 = 1101 1 1 (+1) - (-4) = (-3) *x
001 - 101 = 1100 1 1 (+1) - (-3) = (-4) *x
001 - 110 = 1011 0 0 (+1) - (-2) = (+3) *x
001 - 111 = 1010 0 0 (+1) - (-1) = (+2) *x
010 - 000 = 0010 0 0 (+2) - (+0) = (+2) *x
010 - 001 = 0001 0 0 (+2) - (+1) = (+1) *x
010 - 010 = 0000 0 0 (+2) - (+2) = (+0) *x
010 - 011 = 1111 1 0 (+2) - (+3) = (-1)   
010 - 100 = 1110 1 1 (+2) - (-4) = (-2) *x
010 - 101 = 1101 1 1 (+2) - (-3) = (-3) *x
010 - 110 = 1100 1 1 (+2) - (-2) = (-4) *x
010 - 111 = 1011 0 0 (+2) - (-1) = (+3) *x
011 - 000 = 0011 0 0 (+3) - (+0) = (+3) *x
011 - 001 = 0010 0 0 (+3) - (+1) = (+2) *x
011 - 010 = 0001 0 0 (+3) - (+2) = (+1) *x
011 - 011 = 0000 0 0 (+3) - (+3) = (+0) *x
011 - 100 = 1111 1 1 (+3) - (-4) = (-1) *x
011 - 101 = 1110 1 1 (+3) - (-3) = (-2) *x
011 - 110 = 1101 1 1 (+3) - (-2) = (-3) *x
011 - 111 = 1100 1 1 (+3) - (-1) = (-4) *x
100 - 000 = 0100 1 0 (-4) - (+0) = (-4)   
100 - 001 = 0011 0 1 (-4) - (+1) = (+3)   
100 - 010 = 0010 0 1 (-4) - (+2) = (+2)   
100 - 011 = 0001 0 1 (-4) - (+3) = (+1)   
100 - 100 = 0000 0 0 (-4) - (-4) = (+0) *x
100 - 101 = 1111 1 0 (-4) - (-3) = (-1)   
100 - 110 = 1110 1 0 (-4) - (-2) = (-2)   
100 - 111 = 1101 1 0 (-4) - (-1) = (-3)   
101 - 000 = 0101 1 0 (-3) - (+0) = (-3)   
101 - 001 = 0100 1 0 (-3) - (+1) = (-4)   
101 - 010 = 0011 0 1 (-3) - (+2) = (+3)   
101 - 011 = 0010 0 1 (-3) - (+3) = (+2)   
101 - 100 = 0001 0 0 (-3) - (-4) = (+1) *x
101 - 101 = 0000 0 0 (-3) - (-3) = (+0) *x
101 - 110 = 1111 1 0 (-3) - (-2) = (-1)   
101 - 111 = 1110 1 0 (-3) - (-1) = (-2)   
110 - 000 = 0110 1 0 (-2) - (+0) = (-2)   
110 - 001 = 0101 1 0 (-2) - (+1) = (-3)   
110 - 010 = 0100 1 0 (-2) - (+2) = (-4)   
110 - 011 = 0011 0 1 (-2) - (+3) = (+3)   
110 - 100 = 0010 0 0 (-2) - (-4) = (+2) *x
110 - 101 = 0001 0 0 (-2) - (-3) = (+1) *x
110 - 110 = 0000 0 0 (-2) - (-2) = (+0) *x
110 - 111 = 1111 1 0 (-2) - (-1) = (-1)   
111 - 000 = 0111 1 0 (-1) - (+0) = (-1)   
111 - 001 = 0110 1 0 (-1) - (+1) = (-2)   
111 - 010 = 0101 1 0 (-1) - (+2) = (-3)   
111 - 011 = 0100 1 0 (-1) - (+3) = (-4)   
111 - 100 = 0011 0 0 (-1) - (-4) = (+3) *x
111 - 101 = 0010 0 0 (-1) - (-3) = (+2) *x
111 - 110 = 0001 0 0 (-1) - (-2) = (+1) *x
111 - 111 = 0000 0 0 (-1) - (-1) = (+0) *x
```

so it works, that is a start.

what kind of cases result in a positive number but still a is greater than b  so a - b >= 0 get n = 0 and for those cases when is v = 0 which is when the delta is less than 4 in this case as you cant do a positive 4 but you can do a positive thre.  if the delta is greater then the result continues to go more positive than 4 and that is a signed overflow.

For the case where n = 1  a - b < 0

these cases

```
000 - 100 = 1100 1 1 (+0) - (-4) = (-4) *x  answer +4

001 - 100 = 1101 1 1 (+1) - (-4) = (-3) *x  +5
001 - 101 = 1100 1 1 (+1) - (-3) = (-4) *x  +4

010 - 100 = 1110 1 1 (+2) - (-4) = (-2) *x +6
010 - 101 = 1101 1 1 (+2) - (-3) = (-3) *x +5
010 - 110 = 1100 1 1 (+2) - (-2) = (-4) *x +4

011 - 100 = 1111 1 1 (+3) - (-4) = (-1) *x +7
011 - 101 = 1110 1 1 (+3) - (-3) = (-2) *x +6
011 - 110 = 1101 1 1 (+3) - (-2) = (-3) *x +5
011 - 111 = 1100 1 1 (+3) - (-1) = (-4) *x +4
```

and these are cases where cannot represent the result, signed overflow, but interestingly the comparison still works.